# Adding a field into Workflow Time Trigger Edit Drop Down Menu

Tags: trigger, workflow, time, before-trigger

New here. I'll be as brief as I can.  I'm trying to trigger a mail before a subscription expiry date.

I have two tables: A 'Contact' Table and an 'Account' Table.

How can I add an 'Account Expiry' Date field from the Account table as an option in this drop down?  Or indeed any other new field I create in the Contact table.

Any help appreciated!

[image: workflow time trigger edit]

Comment: Can you please share your work flow rule-criteria as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to create a new formula field on Contact, with type *Date*, referring the Date field on Account.

The formula would be:

```
Account.Account__Expiry__c
```

The new formula field will then appear in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Guy - thought it might be something like that.  Help appreciated.